# Make sure the same ID is not affected to multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database-design

I want to restrict the number of the ID between multiple tables. Let's say I have 4 tables with products. Each table will have an ID, but I want to restrict the number of ID so I can't duplicate it that number already exists on one of these tables. Let's say I have the ID 43 in one table, I want to "deny" it on another table so I can't use it anymore because it's already created on that one.
Thanks!

Comment: What do you have so far? Apart from that you seem to attach an additional meaning to the ID that should probably in a different field.

Comment: This reflects a poor database design. Have you considered foreign keys?

Comment: Perhaps you should rethink your approach and your data-structure. This can get complicated very fast if you don't make it easy from the get-go. It sounds like all this data should be in the same table if you're afraid of duplicating IDs.

Comment: Yeah, it's like joining all the data into one table. But i want to have different tables for each category of products. I don't know how do it with foreign keys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a 5th table for doling out ids.  There, the `id` can be `AUTO_INCREMENT` (if that is suitable).

1. get new number from 5th table
2. `INSERT` into the appropriate of the 4 tables.

The two steps do not need to be in the same 'transaction'.

**A sample sequence generator:**

```
-- Setup:
CREATE TABLE `seq` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `code` char(1) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
INSERT INTO seq VALUES (0, 'a');   -- The only row for the table

-- Increment and get next value:
UPDATE seq
    SET id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id + 1)
    WHERE code = 'a';
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Note: the `UPDATE` and `SELECT` can (should) be done outside any transaction; be in `autocommit=ON` mode.  The `SELECT` is specific to the connection, so there is no chance of mixing up numbers with another connection.

Answer (score 0):

When you INSERT new row, you should, [LOCK all four tables (for data insert)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables.html), start transaction, read max value of ID of each table and choose maximum, add 1 to that maximum and INSERT new row, then finish transaction and unlock tables.

This is basic solution, you can try to optimize it by saving in some place last maximum ID. The table locking ensure that ID will be unique when many concurrent threads (e.g. from php) will insert rows.

May be you will able to do it using triggers (so no on application side but on DB side).

Comment: Seems pretty useful but I'm pretty noob at DB side because the data is going to be modified only on DB side. Could you elaborate your answer, please? Thanks!

Comment: No :) I will not develop your laziness - start learning :) - I give you some keywords in my answer above - google it

Comment: Gotcha, you do not know how to do it either :)

Comment: You caught me! ;)